# Dynamically retrieving input value from React Bootstrap FormControl

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I'm trying to create dynamic react components that would allow me to easily call on a component in any part of my code. One example of such a component, is a modal form. I am making use of [react-bootstrap](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components.html#forms) and I'm trying to stick to using their pre-defined components, but I'm missing something.

I have a Modal form component that creates inputs dynamically from an array that I pass in as a prop.

My component hierarchy looks like this: Crud > ModalForm> InputField

Here is my code:

**crud.js.jsx**

```
...
createModalSubmit(form) {
  console.log(form);

  $.ajax({
    url: '/products.json',
    type: 'POST',
    data:  {product: {
      name: name
    }},
    success: (product) => {
      this.setState({
        product: {
          name: ''
        },
        errors: {},
        showModal: false
      });
    },
    error: (product) => {
      this.setState({errors: product.responseJSON.errors})
    }
  });
},

render: function() {
  var ModalForm = app.ModalForm;
  return (
    <div>
      <ModalForm
        showModal={this.state.showModal}
        headerText="My Modal"
        formElements= {[{"name":"name"}]}
        unloadModal={this.unloadModal}
        buttonText="Add"
        onClickHandler={this.createModalSubmit}
        formErrors={this.state.errors}
        />
    </div>
  );
}
...
```

**modal_form.js.jsx**

```
...
render: function() {
    var Modal = require('react-bootstrap').Modal;
    var InputField = app.InputField

    var formElementsCollection= this.props.formElements.map((formElement, i) => {

      return (
        <InputField
          inputControlID={formElement.name}
          inputLabel={formElement.name}
          key={i}
          />
      )
    });

    return (
      <Modal
        keyboard={true}
        show={this.props.showModal}
        onHide={this.props.unloadModal}
        >
        <Modal.Header closeButton>
          <h3>
            {this.props.headerText}
          </h3>
        </Modal.Header>
        <Modal.Body>
          <form>
            {formElementsCollection}
            <button type="button" className="btn btn-info btn-fill pull-right" onClick={() => this.props.onClickHandler(this)}>{this.props.buttonText}</button>
          </form>
          <div className="clearfix"></div>
        </Modal.Body>
      </Modal>
    );
  }

});
...
```

**input_field.js.jsx**

```
...
getValidationState() {
  const length = this.state.value.length;
  if (length > 10) return 'success';
  else if (length > 5) return 'warning';
  else if (length > 0) return 'error';
},

handleChange(e) {
  this.setState({ value: e.target.value });
},

render: function() {
  var FormGroup = require('react-bootstrap').FormGroup;
  var ControlLabel = require('react-bootstrap').ControlLabel;
  var FormControl = require('react-bootstrap').FormControl;
  return (
    <FormGroup
        controlId={this.props.inputControlID}
        validationState={this.getValidationState()}
      >
      <ControlLabel>{this.props.inputLabel}</ControlLabel>
      <FormControl
        type="text"
        value={this.state.value}
        placeholder={this.props.placeholderText}
        onChange={this.handleChange}
      />
      <FormControl.Feedback />
    </FormGroup>
  );
}
...
```

Before switching to react bootstrap components and when I was still explicitly creating separate forms for every single modal that I required, I would explicitly call on the 'ref' attribute of each input element. What is the best way to retrieve a child element's value dynamically from it's parent?